# What is the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 version number?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have had some "pre-release" versions installed, and want to make sure I actually have the released version installed.

Comment: I found this link to VS 2015 update 2: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx. Maybe this will help.

Comment: No, that link does not show the version number....

Comment: If you run the installer it will detect whether you are on the update 2 version I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine is `14.0.25123.00`, installed from `/layout` generated cache in fresh Windows 10 installation on April 3rd.